# Using putExtra in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

subject2 and grade2 are editText that are converted to String.
this is the code:

```
val subject2 = addSubject.toString()
            val grade2 = addGrade.toString()
            val intent2: Intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
           intent2.putExtra(subject2, grade2)
        }
```

So why when I go the the Main2Activity I see that subject2 and grade2 are an unsolved refrence.
heres the code for Main2Activity:

```
var words = ArrayList<Word>()

        words.add(Word(subject2, grade2))

        words.add(Word("English", "90"))
            words.add(Word("Arabic", "90"))
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `addSubject.text.toString()`, otherwise you'll just get something like `EditText@123124`

Comment: But how can I import it to the Main2Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `putExtra` method of the `Intent` takes in two arguments, one for the name which is a key and the other for the actual value that is being passed -

```
putExtra(String name, String value)
```

In your case, you need to ensure that you pass the values accordingly to the `Activity` as follows -

```
val subject2 = addSubject.toString()
val grade2 = addGrade.toString()
val intent2: Intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
intent2.putExtra("subject", subject2)
intent2.putExtra("grade", grade2)
```

Here `subject` and `grade` are the keys that hold the value of `subject2` and `grade2` respectively. You should use the same keys to retrieve the data from the `Intent` using the `getStringExtra` method in the `Main2Activity` -

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(...)
    .
    .
    .
    val subject2 = intent.getStringExtra("subject")
    val grade2 = intent.getStringExtra("grade")
    .
    .
    var words = ArrayList<Word>()

    words.add(Word(subject2, grade2))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass data from one activity to another.

Here's an example so you can do it:
In activity1:

```
var userName = username.text.toString() 
var password = password_field.text.toString()
intent.putExtra ("KEY1", userName)
intent.putExtra ("KEY2", password)
startActivity (intent)
```

the quotation marks are the keys that will fetch the second acitivity

activity2:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)
    var user: String = intent.getStringExtra("KEY1")
    var pass: String = intent.getStringExtra("KEY2")
    user_name.setText(user)
    password.setText(user)
}
```